# JQuery FlexiGrid with Struts2

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2, flexigrid

**Hi can any one tell me whats wrong with the following code...**

i have configured the Flexigrid in php it is working fine but when i tried it in Struts 2 application it doest display any thing and the loading icon continuously asking to wait...
I m totally unable to display the data in the Flexigrid... i tried a alot but could not get any proper solution... 
But i can see the JSON returned by the server in FireBug i mean the following json response is visible in FireBug but not in FlexiGrid
...Following is my code... plz take a look at the code and point out my mistake... THANKS ALOT

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/candidtrack/web/theme/css/flexigrid/flexigrid.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/candidtrack/web/theme/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/candidtrack/web/theme/lib/flexigrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#flex1").flexigrid
            (
            {
                url: '/candidtrack/web/requirement/requirement!gridInJson',
                                   dataType: 'json',
                colModel : [
                    {display: 'reqId', name : 'reqId', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'reqTitle', name : 'reqTitle', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Job Type', name : 'Job Type', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Company', name : 'Company', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Contact Person', name : 'Contact Person', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Location', name : 'Location', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Submission End Date', name : 'Submission End Date', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Career Level', name : 'Career Level', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Required Skills', name : 'Required Skills', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Education Level', name : 'Education Level', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Residence Status', name : 'Residence Status', width : 95, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Bill Rate', name : 'Bill Rate', width : 35, sortable : true, align: 'right'},
                    {display: 'Status', name : 'Status', width : 45, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                                            {display: 'Action', name : 'Action', width : 35, sortable : true, align: 'center'}
                ],
                buttons : [
                    {separator: true},
                    {name: 'A', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'B', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'C', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'D', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'E', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'F', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'G', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'H', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'I', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'J', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'K', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'L', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'M', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'N', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'O', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'P', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'Q', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'R', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'S', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'T', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'U', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'V', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'W', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'X', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'Y', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: 'Z', onpress: sortAlpha},
                    {name: '#', onpress: sortAlpha}
                ],
                searchitems : [
                    {display: 'reqId', name : 'reqId'},
                    //                                {display: 'Name', name : 'name', isdefault: true}
                ],
                sortname: "reqId",
                sortorder: "asc",
                usepager: true,
                useRp: true,
                rp: 10,
                showTableToggleBtn: true,
                width: 988,
                height: 400
            }
        );


        });
        function sortAlpha(com)
        {


            jQuery('#flex1').flexOptions({newp:1, params:[{name:'letter_pressed', value: com},{name:'qtype',value:$('select[name=qtype]').val()}]});
            jQuery("#flex1").flexReload();



        }

        function test(com,grid)
        {
            if (com=='Delete')
            {
                if($('.trSelected',grid).length>0){
                    if(confirm('Delete ' + $('.trSelected',grid).length + ' items?')){
                        var items = $('.trSelected',grid);
                        var itemlist ='';
                        for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                            itemlist+= items[i].id.substr(3)+",";
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/candidtrack/web/requirement/requirement!gridInJson",
                            data: "items="+itemlist,
                            success: function(data){
                                alert("Query: "+data.query+" - Total affected rows: "+data.total);
                                $("#flex1").flexReload();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (com=='Add')
            {
                alert('Add New Item Action');

            }
        }

    </script>


</head>

<body >

                <table align="center" id="flex1">

                </table>


</body>
```

and the JSON which is returned by server that is displayed on FireBug but could not in the Flexigrid. is::

```
{
page:1 ,
total: 9,
rows: [
{reqId:'1',cell:['1','Title Req1111','Job-ContractToHire','Company 2','Frist Name  mid Last','Location 2','2010-12-12','Career Level 2','Dot NetJava','Bachelor','TN Visa','1/Y']},
{reqId:'2',cell:['2','title ','Job-ContractToHire','Company 2','Salman 8 ItsMe','Location 2','2010-12-01','Career Level 1','Dot Net','','Green Card','234/H']},
{reqId:'3',cell:['3','t','Job-ContractToHire','Company 2','f m l','Location 3','2011-01-29','Career Level 1','','','Citizen','23/H']},
{reqId:'4',cell:['4','t','Job-ContractToHire','Company 2','f m l','Locaion 1','2011-01-11','Career Level 2','','','Green Card','23/H']},
{reqId:'5',cell:['5','t','Job-ContractToHire','Company 2','f m l','Locaion 1','2011-01-11','Career Level 2','','Bachelor','Green Card','23/H']},
{reqId:'7',cell:['7','t','Job-FullTime','comp4','  ','Location 2','2011-03-17','Career Level 2','Any Skill','Bachelor','Green Card','3/H']},
{reqId:'8',cell:['8','tt','Job-Contract','comp4','  ','Location 2','2011-03-23','Career Level 2','Dot Net','','Citizen','3/H']},
{reqId:'9',cell:['9','tt','Job-Contract','comp4','  ','Location 2','2011-03-23','Career Level 2','Dot Net','','Citizen','3/H']},
{reqId:'10',cell:['10','uuu','Job-Contract','comp4','  ','Location 2','2011-03-18','Career Level 1','Java','Bachelor','Citizen','12/H']}]
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

please share your action class code too.
I hope below is the correction
Replace search items with below code

```
searchitems : [          
      {display: 'reqId', name : 'reqId'}
//    {display: 'Name', name : 'name', isdefault: true}
],
```

or need to remove , just before comment